# Linux, how to read a file with execute permission disabled

Tags: linux, permissions, execute

I'm working on homework for a Linux class and we're working on permissions. One thing I have to do is make the owner of a directory allowed to read and write to the directory, but not able to execute. The problem I'm running into is that when I disable execute I can't open any of these files using cat. Is there any other command I can/have to use to read and/or write to the file? It it helps I'm running an older version of fedora.

Update: I have found I can read the files if I disable execute to the files individually, but not if I disable execute to the directory. Is accessing the directory considered executing it? this might have been my problem all along

Answer (score 0):

You do a simple : (the -x is to disable execution if the file get the permission)

```
sudo chmod -x file | cat file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ls -l` to see the read/write/execute permissions and the owner of that file.
Use `chmod` to change the permissions of that file.
Use `chown` to change the owner of that file.
If you're not the owner of that file, and only the owner has read permission, that may be why you're not able to `cat` the file. You can use `whoami` to see what user your shell is running as.

Edit: You need executable permissions on the directory containing the file in order to `cd` into the directory. If the parent directory is not executable, you cannot access the files in that directory. That explains why you couldn't `ls`.

Comment: I am the owner I've checked. The only permission I don't have is execute and also when I use ls -l it won't show me the permissions users have (until I give execute permissions back)

Comment: Do you have the ability to do `sudo ls -l`?
Also, what commands are you using to change the permissions?